# Appcode will not run an App that has no developer certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, appcode

I have an app I am writing for iOS that will run just fine in Xcode but AppCode by Jetbrains says :

```
Error:Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
```

So what I've been doing was keeping Xcode running so that I can hit the "play" button to deploy/compile my app while doing my actual work in AppCode.

Any ideas what could cause this?

[image]

Comment: Whats the version of Xcode and Appcode? Did you choose the appropriate Xcode version in the Appcode preferences?

Comment: 6.11, yes Appcode is set to the same version of Xcode.

Comment: The only thing that I can tell, is that I have repeatedly had this issue (like you) without having been able to fix it and starting the bulit with Xcode. My guess is that Apple sometimes does slight changes to the project format that breaks building or that it's simply a bug...

Comment: Have you tried to reach AppCode support guys? There is dedicated support and community forum, they are responsive I've tried that in my case -> https://www.jetbrains.com/support/objc/

Answer (score 29):

madhurtanwani's link above helped, but I had to scroll to find the solution.

Here is the section that explains the issue and how to solve it:

> It looks like in AppCode you are building for a device and in Xcode for a simulator. Simulator does not perform code signing, so you don't get an error there.
>
> If all you want to do is to run the app in a simulator, then in the toolbar change the selection from "iOS Device" to a desired simulator. To be able to sign the app you need to make sure that you have correct provisioning profile and certificate installed and check your codesign build settings.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and this link on their support site helped me: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5509981#5509981

The crux is that on Xcode I was building for a simulator and in AppCode it was building for an actual device (which requires signing)

Answer (score 1):

I had slightly different problem, and were using real device in both Xcode and AppCode.

I've changed team in one of my projects, and while Xcode were working completely fine, AppCode gave me error: `No signing certificates found`

The only thing that worked for me is changing `Code Signing Identity` from `Apple Development` to `iOS Developer` in `Build Settings` in Xcode:

[image]